# re engineering andEngine 1.0 jar, change and recompile again

Tags: java, class, reverse-engineering, andengine

I am working with AndEngine 1.0 JAR, Now I want to make change to some of its class files. luckily I have its source attached jar file. I have edited its `.java` file but don't know how to recompile those java files into`.class` files.

They don't have tagged their code on their repository so I have only one way and that is java reverse engineering jar file.

Comment: I don't why stackoverflow.com says many times "Question does not meet our quality standards" :@

Answer (score 0):

You weren't looking very hard. The source code is here:

http://code.google.com/p/andengine/source/checkout

Comment: yeah I know but I want version 1.0 and it is not there :(

Answer (score 0):

There is no version "1.0" so you'll actually end up searching forever.

The easiest is probably to checkout the sourcecode, strip out all source-files and drop in the ones from the jar and modify them then.

Anyway you should be using the latest andengine.jar (or sourcecode) for obvious reasons.